# How can we find the values ttl="Series: Count of Customers , Category: Southeast and Value: 10,000 from HTML using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microstrategy

I want to identify the child belongs to multiple div having same class name mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph 
 eg. 1. ttl="Series: Count of Customers
Category: Southeast
Value: 10,000
     2.  ttl="Series: 2016 Running Revenue Average
Category: Southeast
Value: $  883,605
%Category:

```
   <div id="*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905" class="mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph " style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1pt solid rgb(206, 206, 206); width: 614px; height: 354px; left: 34px; top: 175px; z-index: 7; display: block;">
<div class="mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph-txt" style="display: none;"></div>
<img class="mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph " usemap="#*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905_map4" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAmYAAAFiCAYAAABcVRQBAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAB3RJTUUH4QUPBy0Eo0d10gAAFRZJREFUeJzt3b/LG3l+B3A9wc1u3OgfeKot0mwgpBBpj4OL4QgO1xwLJj/YzuTAYAWiQAwOqIgacyGVl1xCYDkXBymuXAxXBRXBkCqsly0eME9xhcrANpPiGO94npnRzGhmvp+RXi8wK331nfl+9CDt963vjEZXWZZlCwAAkvu91AUAAPA7ghkAQBCCGQBAEIIZAEAQghkAQBCCGQBAEIIZAEAQghkAQBCCGQBAEIIZAEAQghkAQBCCGQBAEPf6bLRerxe73e5OW6782LE+XdsB4JjyXGWuYRayjp4+fZo9ffr0TlvT/aY+XdsB4JjyXGWuYS46HcqsWimr4hMHAKm0nasgok6HMpte6JaCAQBO0+scsyrl4/VThLNvv/12ce/eYE8Bg...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" hidefocus="true" style="display: block; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
<map id="*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905_map4" name="*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905_map4">
<area shape="rect" coords="350,328,405,328" ttl="Series: Last Month's Order Count<br/>Category: Southeast<br/>Value: 9,948" aid="0" onclick="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onClickArea(this, event);" oncontextmenu="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onContextMenu(this, event);" onmousemove="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905']._updateTooltip(event, self);">
<area shape="rect" coords="295,325,350,328" ttl="Series: Employee Headcount<br/>Category: Southeast<br/>Value: 4" aid="1" onclick="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onClickArea(this, event);" oncontextmenu="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onContextMenu(this, event);" onmousemove="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905']._updateTooltip(event, self);">
<area shape="rect" coords="241,135,295,328" ttl="Series: Order Count<br/>Category: Southeast<br/>Value: 9,948" aid="2" onclick="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onClickArea(this, event);" oncontextmenu="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onContextMenu(this, event);" onmousemove="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905']._updateTooltip(event, self);">
<area shape="rect" coords="186,48,241,328" ttl="Series: Item Count<br/>Category: Southeast<br/>Value: 360" aid="3" onclick="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onClickArea(this, event);" oncontextmenu="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onContextMenu(this, event);" onmousemove="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905']._updateTooltip(event, self);">
<area shape="rect" coords="131,153,186,328" ttl="Series: Count Order shipped within 5 days<br/>Category: Southeast<br/>Value: 9034" aid="4" onclick="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onClickArea(this, event);" oncontextmenu="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onContextMenu(this, event);" onmousemove="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905']._updateTooltip(event, self);">
<area shape="rect" coords="76,134,131,328" ttl="Series: Count of Customers<br/>Category: Southeast<br/>Value: 10,000" aid="5" onclick="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onClickArea(this, event);" oncontextmenu="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905'].onContextMenu(this, event);" onmousemove="mstrmojo.all['*lK34*kW55*x1*t1494834294905']._updateTooltip(event, self);">
</map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following, which uses dcssSelector to identify the element and then extract "ttl" attribute:

```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSlector("div.mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph map area:nth-child(6)")).getAttribute("ttl");
```

** UPDATE: **

```
  String[] data = driver.findElement(By.cssSlector("div.mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph map area:nth-child(6)")).getAttribute("ttl").split("<br/>");
```

Then you can read data[0], data[1], data[2] separately to get desired output.

**to get 2nd DIV element :**

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSlector("div:nth-child(2) map area:nth-child(6)")).getAttribute("ttl");
```

Comment: what error do you see? you can also make use of actions class' moveToElement() method

Comment: Getting error as below no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph map area[coords*='76,134,131,328']"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
@Kushal :   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.07 seconds

Comment: Make sure your element is not present inside an iframe

Comment: I dont see any tag of iframe

Comment: I got this values for ttl =Series: Count of Customers<br/>Category: Southeast<br/>Value: 10,000 but i need all valllues seprate like Series: Count of Customers,Southeast and 10,000  seprately

Comment: Hi I've updated my answer, that will get you your desired result.

Comment: I have annother class with same name having same child how can we do that , I am able to identify only first class mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph not second how can i check that , I have update the HTML

Comment: I can't see that in you code; better format it in a way I could understand.

Comment: Could you please check now , in first solution i got the child of class for first div but there is second div with same class name so i want the values from that div also, your solution working perfectly for first div with class name mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph but not for second div with same class name

Comment: Any solution on this kushal

Comment: @AbbasALI : I've updated the code for 2nd DIV element, try now.

Comment: Get error as no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.mstrmojo-DocXtabGraph:nth-child(2) map area:nth-child(6)"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.00 seconds